# Interpretation of hierarchical clustered binary dataset

Tags: binary-data, hierarchical-clustering, heatmap

```
set.seed(2020)

b <- replicate(150, rbinom(20,1,0.2))
rownames(b) <- paste("F_", c(1:nrow(b)))
colnames(b) <- paste("ID_", c(1:ncol(b)))

library(pheatmap)
pheatmap::pheatmap(b,clustering_distance_rows = "manhattan",clustering_distance_cols = "manhattan",
                   cutree_cols = 5,cutree_rows = 6,show_rownames = T,show_colnames = F, legend_breaks = c(0,1),legend_labels = c("No","Yes"),color = colorRampPalette(c('blue','green'))(2),scale = "none",treeheight_row = 100,cluster_cols = F)
```

[image]

Now- from the resulting clustered heatmap, what is a reasonable interpretation of the heatmap and clusters?

i.e that F_1 and F_13 tend to co-occur in the samples to the same degree as F_16 & F-17 and that F_18 usually occurs alone? That the large cluster F_2..F-16 occurs as often as F_1 & F-13?

Comment: Hey... i guess since you pretty much generate the matrix using a benoulli trial, maybe makes more sense to generate something with actual signal? Otherwise it's really hard to interpret this result